# Is it possible to catch the history.back event before navigating?

Tags: javascript, web, blazor

I would like to query whether the IsDirty flag is true or false when I click on the back button, but it should be before and not when the navigation is already finished. I'm not sure if this is so easy or if it's a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no "Simple" answer to this problem.  While you can use various strategies within page and navigation menus to restrict dirty form exits, there are no easy one-liner ways to control browser navigation requests.

My current solution to this problem, which addresses all normal form exit mechanisms can be found here [Blazr.Demo.Routing](https://github.com/ShaunCurtis/Blazr.Demo.Routing).

It rebuilds `Router`, adds a new Navigation Manager and interfaces with the browser `beforeunload` event.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. This solution was helpful.